# How do I stop an AWS RDS instance with Ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-rds

How do I *stop* an RDS instance with Ansible rds_instances module?

```
ansible --version

ansible 2.9.10
```

I am trying with the following:

```
- name: Stopping RDS instances for
  rds_instance:
    id: "instance_id" # I have tried also db_instance_identifier, and tried using multiple values from rds_info...
    state: stopped
```

I will get the following error:

```
To create DB instance requires the parameters: ['DBInstanceIdentifier', 'DBInstanceClass', 'Engine']
```

If I specify the missing parameters (although those are not marked as required in the docs), I will get a different error:

```
The error was: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred
(InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CreateDBInstance operation:
Invalid master password
```

Debug does not yield any more new answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh.

I was missing the profile/region parameters, hence it was not able to find the RDS instance. It was looking in a completely different AWS account, because using the default profile. Ansible didn't find the DB, so failed with a creation error.

```
- name: Stopping RDS instances for
  rds_instance:
    id: "instance_id"
    state: stopped
    profile: "{{ profile }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
```